# Constructing a 2 fold oversampled cosine basis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

So I'm trying to construct a 2 fold oversampled cosine basis in MATLAB. I know how to construct the basis as a square matrix using the following command:

$\mbox{dct(eye($n,n$))}$

where dct is the discrete cosine transform function and nxn is the size of my basis but how would I do this if I wanted my basis to be oversampled? Specifically for it to be $n\times2n$, i.e. a fat matrix such that the columns lose the property of linear independence?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simply zeropad the array prior to taking the DCT. Just make sure that the zeros are placed at the higher frequencies.